# Open Office Mail Merge doesn't work

Tags: 10.04, openoffice.org

As far as I can tell, Mail Merge (as well as data sources) is broken in OpenOffice on 10.04. There is no `View | Data Sources` menu option, and the shortcut for `Data Sources` <kbd>F4</kbd> does nothing.

In addition the Mail Merge Wizard doesn't allow any 'Address Book' to actually be added (the `OK` button is never enabled).

Also, `Add Database File...` on the `Database` tab of  `Insert | Fields | Other` (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>) is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*(While composing the question, I stumbled across the solution; however, it didn't turn up in my original search results, so I figured posting it may be helpful to others.)*

[This bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openoffice.org/+bug/185057) has the solution:

> I found the problem: Apparently 8.04 doesn't install OpenOffice base alongside writer and calc. After installing the [openoffice.org-base](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openoffice.org-base) package (plus dependencies), the problems disappeared.

Seems what was true for 8.04 is still true in 10.04.